# I need help using ctypes on jython

Tags: python, ctypes

I want to use libxmp.
I used:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages')
```

which directly locate to libxmp

```
from libxmp import XMPFiles, consts
from libxmp.utils import file_to_dict
```

upper code box is the import part

I faced this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/webprime/jython/jython/jython.py", line 5, in <module>
    from libxmp import XMPFiles, consts
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/libxmp/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from ctypes import util
ImportError: cannot import name util
```

it works on Python 3.

Comment: Isn't Jython still implementing Python 2.7?  You will need to link to a Python 2.7 version of the library.

Comment: Note that Jython is Python2, not Python3: ["The current version of Jython is 2.7.2"](https://www.jython.org/download) The path ``/usr/local/lib/python3.8`` suggests that you have added the library folder of another Python version/implementation to ``PYTHONPATH``. Do not do this; libraries are generally not compatible between versions and implementations.

Comment: thanks i'll try it